# How to catch Android share intents limited to specific URLs using intent-filter?

Tags: android, android-intent, share, intentfilter

I can hook my app into the "Share page" feature using the following intent-filter:

```
<intent-filter>
  <action android:name="android.intent.action.SEND" />
  <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
  <data android:mimeType="text/plain" />
```

But I would like to go a little further and limit the filter to intents with specific URLs in them, for example URL of a YouTube video. I tried something like this but it doesn't work:

```
<intent-filter>
  <action android:name="android.intent.action.SEND" />
  <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
  <data
    android:mimeType="text/plain"
    android:scheme="http"
    android:host="m.youtube.com"
  />
```

Any suggestions?

Comment: I want to do the same. It seems that it is impossible.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> But I would like to go a little further and limit the filter to intents with specific URLs in them, for example URL of a YouTube video.

What you are asking for makes no sense to me as written.

Perhaps you really mean:

> But I would like to go a little further and limit the filter to ACTION_SEND requests where the body extra contains a specific URL

In which case, that is impossible, sorry.

Or, perhaps you really mean:

> But I would like to go a little further and limit the filter to ACTION_SEND requests issued from random pieces of software that happen to be thinking of a specific URL at the time user happened to press "share", such as sharing the current YouTube video being played in the YouTube app

In which case, that is impossible, sorry.

If neither of those guesses really hit what you are asking for, please consider editing your question.

Comment: Thanks, I can see now that it's not possible.

Comment: I don't understand this answer. A developer would like to add sharing support to his app but supports only sharing youtube videos. Thus he wants his app to be triggered only by sharing youtube videos. Why is this impossible?

Comment: @kilaka: It is impossible because you cannot do it. You are welcome to contribute patches to the Android open source project to provide this feature.

Comment: That's the whole point in the host attribute. I would expect the following configuration to work:

    <data android:host="*youtube.com" android:scheme="http"/>

 but I couldn't find a bug on this.

Comment: @kilaka: "That's the whole point in the host attribute" -- `ACTION_SEND` does not use the `host` attribute. The thing you are sharing goes in an `Intent` extra, not the `Uri`.

Comment: @CommonsWare I see it in the documentation. Thank you. http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Intent.html#ACTION_SEND. This is very silly. How come the source of what being sent is not in the data (URI)? CommonsWare, what do you think? Should I open a feature request for this?

Comment: @kilaka: "How come the source of what being sent is not in the data (URI)?" -- because you rarely are sharing something that looks like a `Uri`. For example, I might share this comment, and it does not look like a `Uri`.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/8903/discussion-between-kilaka-and-commonsware)