# Class name to Share via Intent to LinkedIn only

Tags: java, android, eclipse, linkedin-api

I am currently in the process of creating direct intents to a selection of popular platforms in an Android app to share some text. I am currently trying to get a direct intent working with LinkedIn.

I have currently got a direct intent working for Twitter like so:

```
shareIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_SEND);
shareIntent.setClassName("com.twitter.android",
            "com.twitter.android.PostActivity"); 
shareIntent.setType("text/*");
shareIntent.putExtra(android.content.Intent.EXTRA_TEXT, text);           
startActivityForResult(shareIntent, 9);
```

What I need now is the same for LinkedIn. So far I know the base package for LinkedIn after searching on the internet. That being "com.linkedin.android" (Please correct me if this is wrong). However, the key part I am missing is the name of the class that deals with sharing in the LinkedIn app. I.e. com.linkedin.android.?.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I managed to find the intent by extracting the LinkedIn Manifest file from the APK.

The class name is: `com.linkedin.android.home.UpdateStatusActivity`

My code for anyone interested is:

```
if(Utils.doesPackageExist(getSherlockActivity(), "com.linkedin.android"))
{           
    Intent shareIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_SEND);
    shareIntent.setClassName("com.linkedin.android",
            "com.linkedin.android.home.UpdateStatusActivity"); 
    shareIntent.setType("text/*");
    shareIntent.putExtra(android.content.Intent.EXTRA_TEXT, shareText);           
    startActivity(shareIntent);
}
else
{
    Toast.makeText(getSherlockActivity(), "Please install the LinkedIn app to share your result", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
}
```

Credit to Ryszard Wiśniewski for his work on http://code.google.com/p/android-apktool/

Comment: Please note that the above code no longer works with the latest update of the LinkedIn app (April 19, 2013 update). The process above will fail and your app will force close. I have therefore changed the code to get the information from the PackageManager. Please see this SO post: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9730243/android-how-to-filter-specific-apps-for-action-send-intent

Comment: Is there any way to load the app and send the user directly to my profile?

Comment: @RichardLewin, Is there a way to direct open LinkedIn Share dialog as Android Gallery App open after click of linkedIn icon from Share App List., In sort, How to implement shareIntent of Linkedin.

Comment: Instead of this:
shareIntent.setClassName("com.linkedin.android",
            "com.linkedin.android.home.UpdateStatusActivity");
use this:
shareIntent.setPackage("com.linkedin.android");

Comment: Hi, how can I open the app and redirect to a user profile ? in my use case the user can open another user's linkedIn link (to their profile)

Answer (score 0):

As of my writing, the new class name is:

`com.linkedin.android.infra.deeplink.DeepLinkHelperActivity`

So all together:

```
Intent shareIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_SEND);
shareIntent.setClassName("com.linkedin.android",
        "com.linkedin.android.infra.deeplink.DeepLinkHelperActivity"); 
shareIntent.setType("text/*");
shareIntent.putExtra(android.content.Intent.EXTRA_TEXT, shareText);           
startActivity(shareIntent);
```

Comment: throwing ActivityNotFoundException, class name might have changed

Answer (score 0):

It is com.linkedin.android.publishing.sharing.ShareActivity , you can download this app and see what is the current Activity name thats running on your phone   https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.willme.topactivity ... But com.linkedin.android.publishing.sharing.ShareActivity seems its a private class and you can't access as you access Twitter