# How to integrate Linkedin Share on android app

Tags: android, share, linkedin-api

I am new in Android. I want to integrate LinkedIn share on my Android application. Which is the best way to integrate LinkedIn share?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Answer is here:

[Class name to Share via Intent to LinkedIn only](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12599337/class-name-to-share-via-intent-to-linkedin-only)

```
if(Utils.doesPackageExist(getSherlockActivity(), "com.linkedin.android"))
{           
    Intent shareIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_SEND);
    shareIntent.setClassName("com.linkedin.android",
            "com.linkedin.android.home.UpdateStatusActivity"); 
    shareIntent.setType("text/*");
    shareIntent.putExtra(android.content.Intent.EXTRA_TEXT, shareText);           
    startActivity(shareIntent);
}
else
{
    Toast.makeText(getSherlockActivity(), "Please install the LinkedIn app to share your result", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Use the following URL to share a Linkedin URL.  All you need to do to share is insert your URL below...

```
https://www.linkedin.com/sharing/share-offsite/?url={url}
```

This URL has changed, though, several times in the past years.  If you don't want to worry about that anymore, check out this repo, where URL's are regularly tracked and updated by the community: [Github: Social Share URLs](https://github.com/bradvin/social-share-urls).

[image: Social Share URLs]