# Search for linkedin app in android via intent

Tags: android, android-intent, android-sharing

I am using intent to get the list of all apps i can post text to. However, linkedin is not appearing in that list. Do i need to do anything extra for linkedin?

```
        Intent intent = new Intent();
        intent.setAction(Intent.ACTION_SEND);
        intent.setType("text/plain");
        intent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_TEXT, "dcsd");
        package= mContext.getPackageManager();
        List<ResolveInfo> appTargets= package.queryIntentActivities(shareIntent, 0);
```

I am able to get all other apps like Facebook, Twitter except LinkedIn?
What could be the possible reason?

Comment: Perhaps, linkedin is not installed? Do not be blindly assuming that someone **will** have it installed. Handle it gracefully if it is not available.

Comment: linkedin is installed. i'm not posting on linkedin with the above code. just searching the apps i can post to.

Comment: The other possibility, is the linkedin account is not set up and thus sharing is not yet available?

Comment: it's set up properly in the device i'm testing.

Comment: it works on iphone without the sdk. are you sure i need the sdk for android cz it will increase the app size?

Comment: intent.setPackage("com.linkedin"); may be help you

Comment: See this [question and answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12599337/class-name-to-share-via-intent-to-linkedin-only) might help to search on the existing questions here on Stackoverflow instead of posting new questions!

Comment: i repeat : i am not posting to linkedin using the above code. i am trying to get the list of apps i can post to.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[image]

**Code is**

```
Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_SEND);
            intent.setType("text/plain");
            String shareBody = "https://developers.facebook.com/docs/android/share";
            intent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_TITLE,"Share From Test App");
            intent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_TEXT,shareBody);
            intent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_SUBJECT, "hello");
            startActivity(Intent.createChooser(intent, "Share With"));
```

Comment: i found the solution. it's just to add a EXTRA_SUBJECT parameter.

Answer (score 1):

Add this to the intent:

```
intent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_SUBJECT, "dsvs");
```