# Sharing to facebook, twitter via share intent android

Tags: android, facebook, twitter, share

I am currently trying to share text to gmail, facebook and twitter. I am using share intent method to share. Below is the code i used to share

```
Intent sharingIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_SEND);
       sharingIntent.setType("plain/text");
       sharingIntent.putExtra(android.content.Intent.EXTRA_TEXT, "My text");
       startActivity(Intent.createChooser(sharingIntent,"Share using"));
```

The above code only show share options like gmail and skype. Why is facebook and twitter options not shown in the list even though i had the facebook and twitter application installed in my device?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Android - How to filter specific apps for ACTION\_SEND intent](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9730243/android-how-to-filter-specific-apps-for-action-send-intent)

Answer (score 22):

I don't know if anybody still reads this, but if people are still looking I found an easier answer:

```
List<Intent> targetedShareIntents = new ArrayList<Intent>();

Intent facebookIntent = getShareIntent("facebook", "subject", "text");
if(facebookIntent != null)
    targetedShareIntents.add(facebookIntent);

Intent twitterIntent = getShareIntent("twitter", "subject", "text");
    if(twitterIntent != null)
        targetedShareIntents.add(twitterIntent);

Intent gmailIntent = getShareIntent("gmail", "subject", "text");
    if(gmailIntent != null)
        targetedShareIntents.add(gmailIntent);

Intent chooser = Intent.createChooser(targetedShareIntents.remove(0), "Delen");

chooser.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_INITIAL_INTENTS, targetedShareIntents.toArray(new Parcelable[]{}));

startActivity(chooser);
```

And the getShareIntent method (this method searches through the mime type text/plain, you can use other mime types to search through those types or use /*/ to search through all types:

```
private Intent getShareIntent(String type, String subject, String text) 
{
    boolean found = false;
    Intent share = new Intent(android.content.Intent.ACTION_SEND);
    share.setType("text/plain");

    // gets the list of intents that can be loaded.
    List<ResolveInfo> resInfo = getActivity().getPackageManager().queryIntentActivities(share, 0);
    System.out.println("resinfo: " + resInfo);
    if (!resInfo.isEmpty()){
        for (ResolveInfo info : resInfo) {
            if (info.activityInfo.packageName.toLowerCase().contains(type) || 
                    info.activityInfo.name.toLowerCase().contains(type) ) {
                share.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_SUBJECT,  subject);
                share.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_TEXT,     text);
                share.setPackage(info.activityInfo.packageName);
                found = true;
                break;
            }
        }
        if (!found)
            return null;

        return share;
    }
    return null;
}
```

---

If you don't want to use this method you can just create Intents like this:

```
Intent normalIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_SEND);
normalIntent.setType("text/plain");
normalIntent.setPackage("com.katana.facebook"); // I just know the package of Facebook, the rest you will have to search for or use my method.
normalIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_TEXT, "The text you want to share to Facebook");
```

Comment: For google+ I did this: `Intent googlePlusIntent = getShareIntent("plus", "subject", "text");
    if(googlePlusIntent != null)
        targetedShareIntents.add(googlePlusIntent);`

Answer (score 11):

Sharing with Facebook has the problem that it only accepts an url in the EXTRA_TEXT. The native FB app will then grab a text and an image from this url to compose the post. That's not a "bug" but the intended behaviour they give to the official app :-/

Take into account Twitter will only accept text/plain without any markup and with 144 chars at max.

I've made my own "Share" dialog to intercept all different behaviours and give to each target intent what they accepts: HTML, plain text, FB URL and Twitter short text.

Here comes the code:

```
public class ShareHelper implements AdapterView.OnItemClickListener {
            private static final String TAG = ShareHelper.class.getSimpleName();

            private Activity mContext;
            private Dialog mDialog;
            private LayoutInflater mInflater;
            private GridView mGrid;


   private ShareIntentAdapter mAdapter;
        private int mMaxColumns;

        private List<ResolveInfo> plainTextActivities;
        private Set<String> htmlActivitiesPackages;

        private String subject;
        private String textbody;
        private CharSequence htmlbody;
        private String twitterBody;
        private String facebookBody;

        public ShareHelper(Activity context, String subject, String textbody, CharSequence htmlbody, String twitterBody, String facebookBody) {
            this.mContext = context;

            this.subject = subject;
            this.textbody = textbody;
            this.htmlbody = htmlbody;
            this.twitterBody = twitterBody;
            this.facebookBody = facebookBody;
        }

        @SuppressLint("NewApi")
        public void share() {

            this.mInflater = LayoutInflater.from(mContext);

            final Intent sendIntent = new Intent(android.content.Intent.ACTION_SEND);

            sendIntent.setType(HTTP.PLAIN_TEXT_TYPE);
            plainTextActivities = mContext.getPackageManager().queryIntentActivities(sendIntent, 0);

            if (plainTextActivities.size() > 0) { 
                htmlActivitiesPackages = new HashSet<String>();
                sendIntent.setType("text/html");
                final List<ResolveInfo> htmlActivities = mContext.getPackageManager().queryIntentActivities(sendIntent, 0);
                for (ResolveInfo resolveInfo : htmlActivities) {
                    htmlActivitiesPackages.add(resolveInfo.activityInfo.packageName);
                }

                mAdapter = new ShareIntentAdapter();

                final View chooserView = mInflater.inflate(R.layout.dialog_share_us_chooser, null);
                mGrid = (GridView) chooserView.findViewById(R.id.resolver_grid);
                mGrid.setAdapter(mAdapter);
                mGrid.setOnItemClickListener(this);

                mMaxColumns = mContext.getResources().getInteger(R.integer.maxResolverActivityColumns);
                mGrid.setNumColumns(Math.min(plainTextActivities.size(), mMaxColumns));

                AlertDialog.Builder builder;
                if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.HONEYCOMB) {
                    builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(mContext, AlertDialog.THEME_DEVICE_DEFAULT_LIGHT);
                } else {
                    builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(mContext);
                }
                builder.setTitle(R.string.text_share_us_title);
                builder.setView(chooserView);

                mDialog = builder.create();
                mDialog.show();
            } else {
                Toast.makeText(mContext, "No social apps installed to share ChurchLink!", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            }
        }

        @Override
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {

            ResolveInfo info = (ResolveInfo) mAdapter.getItem(position);

            Intent intent = new Intent(android.content.Intent.ACTION_SEND);
            intent.setClassName(info.activityInfo.packageName, info.activityInfo.name);
            intent.setType("text/plain");
            intent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_TITLE, subject);
            intent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_SUBJECT, subject);

            if (info.activityInfo.packageName.contains("facebook")) {
                intent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_TEXT, facebookBody);

            } else if (info.activityInfo.packageName.contains("twitter")) {
                intent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_TEXT, twitterBody);

            } else if (htmlActivitiesPackages.contains(info.activityInfo.packageName)) {
                intent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_TEXT, htmlbody);

            } else {
                intent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_TEXT, textbody);
            }
            Log.d(TAG, info.activityInfo.packageName);
            ((Activity) mContext).startActivity(intent);

            mDialog.dismiss();
        }

        public class ShareIntentAdapter extends BaseAdapter {

            public ShareIntentAdapter() {
                super();
            }

            @Override
            public int getCount() {
                return plainTextActivities != null? plainTextActivities.size() : 0;
            }

            @Override
            public ResolveInfo getItem(int position) {
                return plainTextActivities.get(position);
            }

            @Override
            public long getItemId(int position) {
                return position;
            }

            @Override
            public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
                View view;
                if (convertView == null) {
                    view = mInflater.inflate(R.layout.griditem_share_us, parent, false);
                } else {
                    view = convertView;
                }
                bindView(view, plainTextActivities.get(position));
                return view;
            }

            private final void bindView(View view, ResolveInfo info) {
                TextView text = (TextView)view.findViewById(android.R.id.text1);
                ImageView icon = (ImageView)view.findViewById(android.R.id.icon);

                text.setText(info.activityInfo.applicationInfo.loadLabel(mContext.getPackageManager()).toString());
                icon.setImageDrawable(info.activityInfo.applicationInfo.loadIcon(mContext.getPackageManager()));
            }
        }
    }
```

Seems like some people wants the layout files too. Here are they:

dialog_share_us_chooser.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<GridView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/resolver_grid"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_gravity="center"
    android:clipToPadding="false"
    android:columnWidth="128dp"
    android:numColumns="4"
    android:padding="16dp"
    android:scrollbarStyle="outsideOverlay" />
```

griditem_share_us.xml (from own AOSP project):

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<!--
/* //device/apps/common/res/any/layout/resolve_list_item.xml
**
** Copyright 2006, The Android Open Source Project
**
** Licensed under the Apache License, Version 2.0 (the "License");
** you may not use this file except in compliance with the License.
** You may obtain a copy of the License at
**
**     http://www.apache.org/licenses/LICENSE-2.0
**
** Unless required by applicable law or agreed to in writing, software
** distributed under the License is distributed on an "AS IS" BASIS,
** WITHOUT WARRANTIES OR CONDITIONS OF ANY KIND, either express or implied.
** See the License for the specific language governing permissions and
** limitations under the License.
*/
-->
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
              android:gravity="center"
              android:orientation="vertical"
              android:layout_height="wrap_content"
              android:layout_width="match_parent"
              android:padding="16dp">
<!--               android:background="@android:drawable/activity_picker_bg" -->

    <!-- Activity icon when presenting dialog
         Size will be filled in by ResolverActivity -->
    <ImageView android:id="@android:id/icon"
               android:layout_width="wrap_content"
               android:layout_height="wrap_content"
               android:scaleType="fitCenter" />

    <!-- Activity name -->
    <TextView android:id="@android:id/text1"
              android:layout_width="wrap_content"
              android:layout_height="wrap_content"
              android:gravity="center"
              android:minLines="2"
              android:maxLines="2"
              android:paddingLeft="4dip"
              android:paddingRight="4dip" />
<!--               android:textAppearance="android:attr/textAppearanceSmall" -->
</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: Ooh, please share your solution if possible!

Comment: I'm not sure I'm following this properly. Are you saying that if I store the text I want to post in a file on the device, and then put the URI of that file in the EXTRA_TEXT field, then Facebook's status update activity will load the text from that file, ready to be sent?

Comment: Not really, FB only allows you to post an URL. It's up to them to extract whatever they want from this URL to form the final post. You can make some test to guess the best format of that page to show what you really want on FB. I know they extract an image and some text from it.

Answer (score 4):

If you change the above line to:

`sharingIntent.setType("text/plain");`, Would this problem be resolved?

I think it's `text/plain` , not `plain/text`.

[Reference](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/webkit/MimeTypeMap.html#hasMimeType%28java.lang.String%29) from Android Developers:

> mimeType   A MIME type (i.e. text/plain)

Comment: Thanks! @ss1271 I will change and test it.

Comment: how can i call this adapter in oncreate()??

Comment: @Dimitri sorry but which adapter?

Comment: how to call ShareHelper in a new activity class