# How to share my app to facebook and twitter only?

Tags: android, facebook, android-intent, twitter, android-manifest

I would like to create a button in my app such that upon clicking facebook and twitter options would appear and user can immediately share my app.
Right now my codes are as below but it still doesn't work. Anyone knows the reason? I'm guessing I need to declare it on manifest but how do I go about?

```
public Intent onClick(View arg0) {
    Intent normalIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_SEND);
    normalIntent.setType("text/plain");   
    normalIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_SUBJECT, subject);   
    normalIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_TEXT, content);

    return Intent.createChooser(normalIntent, "Share");
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [Sharing to facebook, twitter via share intent android](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13286358/sharing-to-facebook-twitter-via-share-intent-android)

Comment: @corsair992 i tried using those codes as well but to no avail. my app keeps crashing.

Comment: What error is shown in the logcat?

Comment: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.example.miyoc/com.example.miyoc.MemberMain}: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Couldn't read row 0, col 6 from CursorWindow.  Make sure the Cursor is initialized correctly before accessing data from it.
it says this @corsair992

Comment: This is some other unrelated issue in your code.