# Android Intent directly to Facebook sharing?

Tags: android, facebook

Following code works perfectly,

```
Intent sharingIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_SEND);
sharingIntent.setType("text/plain");
sharingIntent.putExtra(android.content.Intent.EXTRA_TEXT, "text");
sharingIntent.putExtra(android.content.Intent.EXTRA_SUBJECT, "Title");
startActivity(Intent.createChooser(sharingIntent, "Share using"));
```

but it open a list and from this list I have to select Facebook and then everything is smooth.

But is there any config changes that can open Facebook sharing directly instead of going through the menu.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try the following code, now the intent will open Facebook directly.

```
List<Intent> targetedShareIntents = new ArrayList<Intent>();

Intent facebookIntent = getShareIntent("facebook", "subject", "text_or_url");
// subject may not work, but if you have a url place it in text_or_url
if(facebookIntent != null)
    targetedShareIntents.add(facebookIntent);

Intent chooser = Intent.createChooser(targetedShareIntents.remove(0), "Delen");

chooser.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_INITIAL_INTENTS, targetedShareIntents.toArray(new Parcelable[]{}));

startActivity(chooser);
```

// To precisely get the facebook intent use the following code

```
private Intent getShareIntent(String type, String subject, String text) 
{
    boolean found = false;
    Intent share = new Intent(android.content.Intent.ACTION_SEND);
    share.setType("text/plain");

    // gets the list of intents that can be loaded.
    List<ResolveInfo> resInfo = getActivity().getPackageManager().queryIntentActivities(share, 0);
    System.out.println("resinfo: " + resInfo);
    if (!resInfo.isEmpty()){
        for (ResolveInfo info : resInfo) {
            if (info.activityInfo.packageName.toLowerCase().contains(type) || 
                    info.activityInfo.name.toLowerCase().contains(type) ) {
                share.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_SUBJECT,  subject);
                share.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_TEXT,     text);
                share.setPackage(info.activityInfo.packageName);
                found = true;
                break;
            }
        }
        if (!found)
            return null;

        return share;
    }
    return null;
}
```

Above code is extracted from this [stackoverflow-post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/20195776/3141985)

Comment: It works fine when I put a try catch block in onCreate part of the activity,  but I am getting `Activity com.android.internal.app.ChooserActivity has leaked IntentReceiver com.android.internal.app.ResolverActivity$1@417c15b0 that was originally registered here. Are you missing a call to unregisterReceiver()?` error

Answer (score 1):

this should be possible, if you get first all activities, that supports your intent and then get the correct and do a explicit call. To get all activities use `context.getPackageManager.queryIntentActivities(Intent, int)`. The coding shouldn't be a big problem.

Check this link: [PackageManager docu](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/pm/PackageManager.html#queryIntentActivities%28android.content.Intent,%20int%29)

Comment: I am not an expert, but do you mean that I have to iterate through the list of all items displayed, but will it then show only Facebook in that list and then click Facebook again ?

Comment: No you iterate and look for the fb intent and call this explicit.