# How do i customize the icon and label shown in Share intent?

Tags: android, android-intent

I have an app named 'TwiOld'. It is an extension to twitter for Android app.

This how i start it : open twitter app , select a tweet and hit share button.

How do i have same app name in launcher and different label (circled below in image) in share menu ?

[image]

Comment: Show me how you set up your icon in the manifest file.

Answer (score 1):

It's the same icon as your application icon.

Comment: I think he is asking how to change the label and not the icon

Comment: Ah, yeah, could be possible. I'll edit my answer accordingly.

Comment: @Leandros yeah..i am more concerned about Label instead of icon.

Answer (score 0):

Try using LabeledIntent, see usage example here:
[How to filter specific apps for ACTION_SEND intent (and set a different text for each app)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9730243/how-to-filter-specific-apps-for-action-send-intent-and-set-a-different-text-for)

you could set the text using this
*constructor*

> LabeledIntent(Intent origIntent, String sourcePackage, CharSequence nonLocalizedLabel, int icon)
>
> Create a labeled intent from the given intent, supplying a textual label and icon resource for it.

taken from:

https://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/pm/LabeledIntent.html

Answer (score 0):

In your manifest, simply add the label and icon attributes to your intent activity.

```
<activity
        android:name=".IntentActivity"
        android:enabled="true"
        android:exported="true"

        android:icon="@drawable/custom_icon"
        android:label="@string/custom_label">
        <intent-filter>
        ...
        </intent-filter>
</activity>
```