# How can I get result for share intent?

Tags: android

I'm using next code for sharing:

```
Intent sendIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_SEND); 
sendIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_TEXT, getString(R.string.share_text));
sendIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_STREAM, Uri.fromFile(file));
sendIntent.setType("image/png");
startActivityForResult(Intent.createChooser(sendIntent,
    getResources().getString(R.string.share_via)), REQUEST_SHARE_RESULT);
```

And I want checking result for this intent in my `onActivityResult()` function. But it's always return `Activity.RESULT_CANCELED`. Even sharing was successed. Why???

Answer (score -1):

In your child activity, you must call `setResult()` before calling `finish()`; this is how the child returns its result to the parent's `onActivityResult()` method.

Comment: I'm know about it. My task is get sharing results from Gmail, Twitter and others. I can't using setResult() for them... I'm want to know result was successed or sharing operation was cancelled by user.

Comment: @mah, I am still looking for answer for the same. My app name is ABC and I am sharing data from app ABC to Facebook or WhatsApp. Now how will app ABC will know that data was shared to Facebook or WhatsApp using the method `createChooser`? Now I would recommend a link which shows alternate way http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9730243/how-to-filter-specific-apps-for-action-send-intent-and-set-a-different-text-for

Comment: ok then according to you what is the output when you use the function `Intent.createChooser()`. Try out

Answer (score -1):

try this example for startActivityForResult().
http://saigeethamn.blogspot.in/2009/08/android-developer-tutorial-for_31.html,
http://android.rahulblogs.com/android-startactivityforresult-example/

Comment: I cannot set `setResult` which those tutorials suggested. I am sharing my data via Gmail, WhatsApp, etc. where I cant use `setResult`

Comment: @mah, now you taking it personally. And there is a function named `createChooser` which shows the list of other apps and where I cannot put the function `setResult` in other app than mine

Comment: @mah just final comment. I don't think there is any use to argue with you. Have you ever used the method `Intent.createChooser`? If no then use it once, then compare your answer. Also read the comment of the user on your reply who posted the question. Abusing or not I don't know but I'm sure you just arguing for getting vote down on your reply. You are just revenge seeker for me