# android Intent.ACTION_SEND filter

Tags: android, filter

I want Disable Some app intent when i calling Intent.ACTION_SEND. I dont want show gmail, email, bluetooth when i call Intent.ACTION_SEND. There is ant way?.

```
  try
        { Intent i = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_SEND);  
          i.setType("text/plain");
          String sAux = linkok;
          i.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_TEXT, sAux);  
          startActivity(Intent.createChooser(i, "choose one"));
        }
        catch(Exception e)
        { //e.toString();
        }
```

Comment: I think you have to create your custom Chooser

Comment: Possible duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9730243/android-how-to-filter-specific-apps-for-action-send-intent

Comment: Yes how? Can you explain more?

Comment: I dont want Choose i want disable some app...

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/10035789/1168654