# ACTION_SEND doesn't send text with image to Facebook

Tags: android, sharing

I wanna enable sharing image + text to all apps in Android that why I used ACTION_SEND .. but my problem is that it doesn't work with Facbook, although it's working with other apps but with face book it only get the image without the text ... any solution ?

```
Intent sharingIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_SEND);
Uri screenshotUri = Uri.parse("file:///sdcard/image.jpg");
sharingIntent.setType("image/*");
sharingIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_TEXT, "Body text of the new
status");
sharingIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_STREAM, screenshotUri);
startActivity(Intent.createChooser(sharingIntent, "Share image
using"));
```

Comment: it's a Facebook "bug", or ... a "contract" that is not respected by the Facebook app. report this to them.

Comment: I don't think its a bug, I think its intentional.

Comment: @StevenMann why would it be intentional ??

Comment: Because facebook requires auth for everything else... you have to log in on a per-app basis: they want to be able to deal with malicious apps more effectively.

Comment: Please check this link: https://developers.facebook.com/bugs/332619626816423

Comment: @image and text both not allowed at once as per http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9730243/android-how-to-filter-specific-apps-for-action-send-intent