# Share different text to different apps using intent chooser

Tags: android, email, android-intent

I am using intent chooser to give the options to user through which he can share.

Now, I want to customize it such that if it is an Email, add a specific subject and text.
Else in other apps like Facebook and twitter, combine the above specified subject and message as a post or tweet.

How can I do so?

Also how can we differentiate between email client and other apps?

Comment: See: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9730243/android-how-to-filter-specific-apps-for-action-send-intent