# I want to open the dialog list of installed messaging apps like (WhatsApp etc.) when I touch the send sms button

Tags: android

I am using the code below.

```
Intent sendIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_SENDTO);         
            sendIntent.setData(Uri.parse("smsto:" + phno));
            sendIntent.putExtra("sms_body", msg);
            sendIntent.putExtra("exit_on_sent", true);
            startActivity(sendIntent);
```

What should I add more?

Answer (score 0):

You are looking for **Share via Intent**, something like:

```
Intent intent=new Intent(android.content.Intent.ACTION_SEND);
intent.setType("text/plain");
//the line below is optional
intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_WHEN_TASK_RESET);

// Add data to the intent, the receiving app will decide what to do with it.
intent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_SUBJECT, “Some Subject Line”);
intent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_TEXT, “Body of the message”);
```

Also, you can use `createChooser()`:

```
startActivity(Intent.createChooser(intent, “How do you want to share?”));
```

Refer:
[How to filter specific apps for ACTION_SEND intent (and set a different text for each app)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9730243/android-how-to-filter-specific-apps-for-action-send-intent)

http://android-developers.blogspot.in/2012/02/share-with-intents.html

Check this too:
http://developer.android.com/training/sharing/send.html

Comment: @donison24x7 you will have to search a bit for your implementation, else the code that i have mentioned should work, just to check how the call takes place