# Display particular type of apps in Intent

Tags: android, android-intent

I have an app which displays results in webView. Results may include formats like `.pdf, .ps, .dwf, .kml, .kmz, .xls, .ppt, .doc, .docx, .rtf and .swf`
Now when user click on .pdf type link the I would like to display apps which can support pdf format like "google docs", "pdf reader" etc. Similarly, when user clicks any `.swf` file then apps which support swf files like "swf player"get listed in the intent.
I have download listener like this:

```
webView.setDownloadListener(new DownloadListener() {
            public void onDownloadStart(String url, String userAgent, String contentDisposition, String mimetype, long contentLength) {
                Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_SEND);
                intent.setDataAndType(Uri.parse(url).normalizeScheme(), Intent.normalizeMimeType(mimetype));
                startActivity(Intent.createChooser(intent, "Open link via..."));
            }
        });
```

But I didn't get expected results.
How to achieve this ?
I don't want to download the file first and then open it. Also, I avoid using this approach:
`webView.loadUrl("http://docs.google.com/gview?embedded=true&url=http://example.com/xyz.pdf");`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I use something like that in my project, so just attach yout link/downloaded file, to it:

```
SharedMethods.openFile(getActivity(), new File(filePath));
```

and my `SharedMethods.openFile`:

```
public static void openFile(Context context, File url) throws IOException {
    Uri uri = Uri.fromFile(url);

    Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
    if (url.toString().contains(".doc") || url.toString().contains(".docx")) {
        intent.setDataAndType(uri, "application/msword");
    } else if(url.toString().contains(".pdf")) {
        intent.setDataAndType(uri, "application/pdf");
    } else if(url.toString().contains(".ppt") || url.toString().contains(".pptx")) {
        intent.setDataAndType(uri, "application/vnd.ms-powerpoint");
    } else if(url.toString().contains(".xls") || url.toString().contains(".xlsx")) {
        intent.setDataAndType(uri, "application/vnd.ms-excel");
    } else if(url.toString().contains(".rtf")) {
        intent.setDataAndType(uri, "application/rtf");
    } else if(url.toString().contains(".gif")) {
        intent.setDataAndType(uri, "image/gif");
    } else if(url.toString().contains(".jpg") || url.toString().contains(".jpeg") || url.toString().contains(".png")) {
        intent.setDataAndType(uri, "image/jpeg");
    } else if(url.toString().contains(".txt")) {
        intent.setDataAndType(uri, "text/plain");
    } else if(url.toString().contains(".odt")) {
        intent.setDataAndType(uri, "application/vnd.oasis.opendocument.text");
    }  else if(url.toString().contains(".ods")) {
        intent.setDataAndType(uri, "application/vnd.oasis.opendocument.spreadsheet");
    }  else if(url.toString().contains(".wps")) {
        intent.setDataAndType(uri, "application/vnd.ms-works");
    } else {
        intent.setDataAndType(uri, "*/*");
    }

    intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK); 
    context.startActivity(intent);
}
```

Hope it helped.

Comment: I think this implementation will work only if we have pre-downloaded file(.doc, .pdf etc). Will this work if we have "web url" of these formats like "http://example.com/xyz.pdf" , "http://example.com/xyz.doc" etc

Comment: if you get file extension from URL, or file type from response header, you can change my method and pass these data... anyway, I think, that you can open file in android only if you have downloaded it previously.

Comment: Yeah I can extract the file type and even file name like **xyz.pdf** or **xyz.doc**, but still I don't think I can open it directly without downloading. Is there no other solution for this other than downloading these files prior to open them ?

Comment: If apps on Android can download files from given URL, than it's possible, but for 3-4years as I use Android phones I didn't find out that possibility ;)

Answer (score 0):

You can filter result for list of applications, here is one existing post that well explains,
[How to filter specific apps for ACTION_SEND intent (and set a different text for each app)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9730243/android-how-to-filter-specific-apps-for-action-send-intent)

Comment: I don't want to specify particular apps. Instead I would like to display apps of particular type means all apps which may support pdf or all apps which support doc and likewise.