# How to filter out a specified app from the intent app list?

Tags: android, android-intent

Here is the background:
I'm writing an android app which can provide image/* to other apps, it also can import image/* from other apps.
What's interesting is:
This app will be displayed in the app list when it requires images from other apps, but I don't want this.

```
Intent intent = new Intent();
intent.setType("image/*");
intent.setAction(Intent.ACTION_GET_CONTENT);

Bundle bundle = new Bundle();
intent.putExtras(bundle);    

myActivity.startActivityForResult(Intent.createChooser(intent, ac.getText(R.string.select_image)), MY_REQUEST_CODE);
```

So, my question is: is there any solution to remove itself from the app list when it is requiring content from other apps?

SOS...
Thank you so much!

Comment: check this thread http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9730243/android-how-to-filter-specific-apps-for-action-send-intent