# Formatted text in ACTION_SEND intent

Tags: android, android-intent, text, formatted

I want to share a **formatted** text from Android application using **ACTION_SEND** intent and I've found I can use the  tag.
It works well sharing the HTML text with email, but if I try to share it with Facebook, Twitter, Hangout, no text is showed. Of course they can't interpret the HTML code.
How can I handle the different sharing ways with the code formatted ?
This is the code:

```
    Spanned shareBody = Html.fromHtml(context.getString(R.string.suggest_text));
    Intent sharingIntent = new Intent(android.content.Intent.ACTION_SEND);
    sharingIntent.setType("text/plain");
    sharingIntent.putExtra(android.content.Intent.EXTRA_SUBJECT, context.getString(R.string.suggest_subject));
    sharingIntent.putExtra(android.content.Intent.EXTRA_TEXT, shareBody);
    startActivity(Intent.createChooser(sharingIntent, context.getString(R.string.share_with)));
```

and this is the value in strings.xml

```
<string name="suggest_text">
    <![CDATA[
    <p>Hey,</p>

    <p>good morning</p>
    <p><a href="http://www.someurl.bla">Click here</a>

   ]]>
   </string>
```

Comment: Check : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9730243/android-how-to-filter-specific-apps-for-action-send-intent

Answer (score 2):

Try like this

```
shareIntent.putExtra(
Intent.EXTRA_TEXT,
Html.fromHtml(new StringBuilder()
    .append("<p><b>Hey,</b></p>")
    .append("<small><p>good morning</p></small>")
    .toString())
);
```