# how to filter email clients using ACTION_SEND in android

Tags: android, email, android-intent

i am developing an application which is related to email sharing. and sharing using ACTION_SEND intent is great, but the problem is I don't want every sharing option there, I'd rather limit it to FB, Twitter. I want to display only email clients.

And i tried **ACTION_SENDTO** intent also instead of ACTION_SEND then getting "No apps can perform this action". how to resolve this?  please anyone have idea please help me..

Thanks in advance..

Comment: You should check out this example: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9730243/how-to-filter-specific-apps-for-action-send-intent-and-set-a-different-text-for

Comment: i seen above link and tried but getting which apps are supported intent.setType("message/rfc822") like hike,skype,messages etc..

Answer (score 0):

Use `intent.setPackage("com.google.android.gm")` - Set your package (make sure to check if the package exists or not). to use gmail for sharing.

Above will send mail directly going with gmail.
But there is another way is :
Try

```
Intent emailIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_SENDTO, Uri.fromParts(
                "mailto", mailId, null));
        emailIntent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
        emailIntent.setType("message/rfc822");
startActivity(Intent.createChooser(emailIntent, "Send Mail"));
```

Comment: thanks for reply... but i don't want redirect to any app directly.. i want to show all email options to user then user have a choice to select among those..

Comment: i tried second one also in this case i'm getting dialog with message "No apps can perform this action"

Comment: I think sohil's link is correct example to that way. Just remove some unnecessary conditions from `for loop`.

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9730243/how-to-filter-specific-apps-for-action-send-intent-and-set-a-different-text-for

Comment: i think its not helped to me because i need what email applications were installed in device but in that he is checking manually right.. we don't know  all email applications right so how do we figure out it what the app user using?

Comment: `emailIntent.setType("message/rfc822");` This is used to set intent as mail intent.
And make action to Intent.ACTION_SEND.

Comment: using the above what you mentioned i'm getting 6 clients (Gmail,hike,skype,Gmail,Drive,messages). getting duplicates also like Gmail..