# Android - Open a file with specific app using intent

Tags: android, android-intent

How can I open a .pdf file with a specific app like adobe reader using an intent?
Something like:

```
Intent intent = getPackageManager().getLaunchIntentForPackage("com.package.name");
intent.setData(Uri.fromFile(file)); //? - set file to open
startActivity(intent);
```

I don't want to select an app from a list, the intent must open the file using the specified app.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you want to open other application then you have to give package name.

Check below code.

```
try {
    Intent mIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW); 

    mIntent.setDataAndType(Uri.fromFile(file), "application/pdf");
    mIntent.setPackage("com.adobe.reader");
    startActivity(Intent.createChooser(mIntent, "View PDF"));
} catch (Exception e) {
    //App not found
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

If you want to open anyother PDF Viewer app then just change PackageName Instead of **"com.adobe.reader"**

Comment: Almost, the above code opens the specified app but not the file, I've tested it also with a .txt file using an app called Text Editor by Byte Mobile, same thing.  Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

You can use this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/18068122/4170584) on another thread. It is for ACTION_SEND, but you can adapt it for ACTION_VIEW in your case.