# Opening Default Camera using Intent , overriding other apps?

Tags: android, android-camera

I am trying to open the camera from my app, however as there are other apps installed, such as `candy` and `retrica` , phone asks which one to open. However, I want to open the default camera, by default in every devices. Any solution?  Here is my code:

```
public void cameraFuture(View view)
{
    Intent intent = new Intent(android.provider.MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE);
    startActivityForResult(intent, 0);
}

protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
    ImageView iv = (ImageView)findViewById(R.id.camTemp);

    Bitmap bp = (Bitmap) data.getExtras().get("data");
    iv.setImageBitmap(bp);
}
```

Comment: have a look here  https://developer.android.com/guide/components/intents-common.html at (Example intent filter). not sure but that category - default might work, although i haven't tried myself

Comment: May be duplicate of *[How to restrict use of third party camera app from your app
android-camera](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31852200/how-to-restrict-use-of-third-party-camera-app-from-your-app)*

Answer (score 0):

1. First of all get the package name of the camera you want to open by default .(if you need i will let you know how to get this)
2. just write this code. change the package name you got for that camera - setPackage("**place the new package name in here**")  method

   Intent mIntent = null;
   mIntent = new Intent();
   mIntent.setPackage("com.sec.android.app.camera");
   mIntent.setAction(android.provider.MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE);
   enter code herestartActivity(mIntent);