# Send data to PhoneNumber Intent

Tags: android, android-intent

```
Intent shareIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_SEND);
shareIntent.setType("text/plain");
shareIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_TEXT, text);
shareIntent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
startActivity(Intent.createChooser(intent, "Invite with"));
```

The above code opens a dialog showing following apps:- Bluetooth, Email, Whatsapp, messages.

What i want to achieve is show all apps that uses phone number as primary source of contacting users. Eg. sms, whatsapp,viber..etc.
Email Apps, Browsers... would not be on the list.

Thanks.

Comment: See this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9730243/how-to-filter-specific-apps-for-action-send-intent-and-set-a-different-text-for

Comment: Please explain, in actual computer programming terms, what defines "apps that uses phone number as primary source of contacting users".

Comment: @CommonsWare what i meant is : Apps that can send data to recipient via phone number. Like the message app on a users device, whatsapp uses phone number as well, viber is another example. But Email applications does not do this, browsers, file sharing apps.. etc.

Comment: That's an end-user statement. In **actual computer programming terms**, what defines "apps that uses phone number as primary source of contacting users"?