# Sharing text from app to Email app in android

Tags: android, email, android-intent, share

I have the following code which used to send text from my app to Email:

```
Intent mail = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
            mail.setClassName("com.google.android.gm","com.google.android.gm.ComposeActivityGmail");
                mail.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_EMAIL, new String[] {  });
                mail.setData(Uri.parse(""));
                mail.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_SUBJECT, "Country Decryption");
                mail.setType("plain/text");
                mail.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_TEXT, "my text");
                ctx.startActivity(mail);
```

It works , but as you see, it uses Gmail app, how do I make it use Email application instead of Gmail?

I mean this app:
[image: email app]

and what about sharing to Facebook ? I found that Facebook does not support sharing using intent anymore, and I have to use Facebook SDK, but I couldn't find any simple procedure to do that. Is there any simple way?

Regards.

Comment: I am thinking you could just filter all apps that use the SEND intents. For Faceboo SDK, their developer page has some useful documentation https://developers.facebook.com/docs/android

Comment: There is no requirement that a device have an app named "Email", and there is no requirement for devices that *do* have an app named "Email" to all have the *same* app named "Email". And, there is no requirement for the user to want to use "Email" or Gmail for sending email messages, as they may prefer some other email client.

Comment: thanks dear, but i mean by Email the default mail app used in android ! it come integrated with any android phone ! go to any thing in your phone and click share via ! you will find Email app which i talked about.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

well to use other email apps am afraid you would have to create a chooser dialog and let the user choose which app to use, something like this

```
Intent emailIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_SENDTO, Uri.fromParts(
        "mailto","abc@mail.com", null));
emailIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_EMAIL, "address");
emailIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_SUBJECT, "Subject");
emailIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_TEXT, "Body");
startActivity(Intent.createChooser(emailIntent, "Send Email..."));
```

Comment: thanks, good progress, now chooser opened and i have to choose between Gmal or Email , how i open Email automatically ?

Comment: as for as i know You cant, this is what i wrote in start.

Comment: why ?! in my code, Gmail used as default , why i cant use Email instead of Gmail ?!

Comment: your answer is the most relative to my case, thank you.

Answer (score 1):

You have to create a specific filter on your ACTION_SEND and you can read a complete answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/18068122/1222099).

This is the code in which you can choose which app show in the app chooser

```
List<ResolveInfo> resInfo = pm.queryIntentActivities(sendIntent, 0);
    List<LabeledIntent> intentList = new ArrayList<LabeledIntent>();        
    for (int i = 0; i < resInfo.size(); i++) {
        // Extract the label, append it, and repackage it in a LabeledIntent
        ResolveInfo ri = resInfo.get(i);
        String packageName = ri.activityInfo.packageName;
        if(packageName.contains("android.email")) {
            emailIntent.setPackage(packageName);
        } else if(packageName.contains("twitter") || packageName.contains("facebook") || packageName.contains("mms") || packageName.contains("android.gm")) {
            Intent intent = new Intent();
            intent.setComponent(new ComponentName(packageName, ri.activityInfo.name));
            intent.setAction(Intent.ACTION_SEND);
            intent.setType("text/plain");
            if(packageName.contains("twitter")) {
                intent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_TEXT, resources.getString(R.string.share_twitter));
            } else if(packageName.contains("facebook")) {
                // Warning: Facebook IGNORES our text. They say "These fields are intended for users to express themselves. Pre-filling these fields erodes the authenticity of the user voice."
                // One workaround is to use the Facebook SDK to post, but that doesn't allow the user to choose how they want to share. We can also make a custom landing page, and the link
                // will show the <meta content ="..."> text from that page with our link in Facebook.
                intent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_TEXT, resources.getString(R.string.share_facebook));
            } else if(packageName.contains("mms")) {
                intent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_TEXT, resources.getString(R.string.share_sms));
            } else if(packageName.contains("android.gm")) { // If Gmail shows up twice, try removing this else-if clause and the reference to "android.gm" above
                intent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_TEXT, Html.fromHtml(resources.getString(R.string.share_email_gmail)));
                intent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_SUBJECT, resources.getString(R.string.share_email_subject));               
                intent.setType("message/rfc822");
            }

            intentList.add(new LabeledIntent(intent, packageName, ri.loadLabel(pm), ri.icon));
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

This works to intent just the gmail app.

```
Intent sharingIntent = new Intent(android.content.Intent.ACTION_SEND);
        sharingIntent.setType("text/plain");
        sharingIntent.setPackage("com.google.android.gm");
        String shareBody = "Here is the share content body";
        sharingIntent.putExtra(android.content.Intent.EXTRA_SUBJECT, "Subject Here");
        sharingIntent.putExtra(android.content.Intent.EXTRA_TEXT, shareBody);
        startActivity(sharingIntent);
```