# How to send mail on button clicked Android Studio?

Tags: android, android-studio, email, android-intent

I want to send e-mail and when button is clicked I want list of e-mail based applications . When I use below source code it outputs all message based apps as showin in picture

```
Intent intent2 = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_SEND);
intent2.setData(Uri.parse("mailto:"));
intent2.setType("plain/text");
intent2.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_EMAIL, new String[]{email});
startActivity(intent2);
```

When I click on button, such apps are showing

[image]

> but I want only e-mail based apps, such as. **What I should change to get such list of apps?**

[image]

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/37008125/3154636

Answer (score 5, accepted):

you can use this

```
 btnReport.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            String mailto = "mailto:useremail@gmail.com" +
                    "?cc=" +
                    "&subject=" + Uri.encode("your subject") +
                    "&body=" + Uri.encode("your mail body");
            Intent emailIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_SENDTO);
            emailIntent.setData(Uri.parse(mailto));

            try {
                startActivity(emailIntent);
            } catch (ActivityNotFoundException e) {
                Toast.makeText(context, "Error to open email app", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
        }
    });
```

Comment: doesnt using sendto eliminate the use of attachments.

Answer (score 0):

Just call an intent for Email in your onClicklistener,

```
Intent email = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_SEND);  
email.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_EMAIL, new String[]{ to});  
email.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_SUBJECT, subject);  
email.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_TEXT, message);  

//need this to prompt`enter code here`s email client only  
email.setType("message/rfc822");  

startActivity(Intent.createChooser(email, "Choose an Email client :"));
```

Comment: no change, it also shows WhatsApp, Telegram, Bluetooth apps