# share the description along with image in facebook not working

Tags: android, android-sharing

I want to share image along with caption in all possible app including `facebook`.
I tried this code,it is working for all the other apps except `facebook`.Can anyone please help me how to share the caption along with image in `facebook`.

```
    Intent shareIntent = new Intent();
    shareIntent.setAction(Intent.ACTION_SEND);
    shareIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_STREAM, bmpUri);
    shareIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_TEXT, caption);
    shareIntent.setType("image/*");
    mcontext.startActivity(Intent.createChooser(shareIntent, "Share Image"));
```

Comment: To share text with image you have to integrate facebook SDK into your app

Answer (score 0):

**Try this.**

> Store your image in external storage directory and take path of that image and for text use `android.content.Intent.EXTRA_TEXT` and pass your static text.

```
String fileName = "imagename.jpg";//Name of an image
String externalStorageDirectory = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().toString();
String myDir = externalStorageDirectory + "/saved_images/"; // the file will be in saved_images
Uri uri = Uri.parse("file:///" + myDir + fileName);
Intent intentShare = new Intent(android.content.Intent.ACTION_SEND);
intentShare.setType("text/plain");
intentShare.putExtra(android.content.Intent.EXTRA_SUBJECT, "Testing Subject");
intentShare.putExtra(android.content.Intent.EXTRA_TEXT, "Testing Texts");
intentShare.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_STREAM, uri);


PackageManager pm = v.getContext().getPackageManager();
   List<ResolveInfo> activityList = pm.queryIntentActivities(shareIntent, 0);
     for (final ResolveInfo app : activityList) 
     {
         if ((app.activityInfo.name).startsWith("com.facebook.katana")) 
         {
           final ActivityInfo activity = app.activityInfo;
           final ComponentName name = new ComponentName(activity.applicationInfo.packageName, activity.name);
          shareIntent.addCategory(Intent.CATEGORY_LAUNCHER);
          shareIntent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK | Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_RESET_TASK_IF_NEEDED);
          shareIntent.setComponent(name);
          v.getContext().startActivity(shareIntent);
          break;
        }
      }
```

> Include this permissions in your manifest.

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"/>
```

Comment: Check i have edited my answer. do it using package manager class i have added.

Comment: If  I use "com.facebook.katana" then it allows to share only for the facebook app not for  the other apps

Comment: Yes `intent send` would not share and allow it directly to facebook. it will do it for all other but for facebook you need to use it's package for identification. only way to do it with this or else you may use `Facebook SDK`.

Comment: @RagamaiK Check this link and answer given here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9730243/how-to-filter-specific-apps-for-action-send-intent-and-set-a-different-text-for

Answer (score -1):

```
public void onShareClick(View v){
    List<Intent> targetShareIntents=new ArrayList<Intent>();
    Intent shareIntent=new Intent();
    shareIntent.setAction(Intent.ACTION_SEND);
    shareIntent.setType("text/plain");
    List<ResolveInfo> resInfos=getPackageManager().queryIntentActivities(shareIntent, 0);
    if(!resInfos.isEmpty()){
        for(ResolveInfo resInfo : resInfos){
            String packageName=resInfo.activityInfo.packageName;
            Log.i("Package Name", packageName);
            if(packageName.contains("com.twitter.android") || packageName.contains("com.facebook.katana") ){
                Intent intent=new Intent();
                intent.setComponent(new ComponentName(packageName, resInfo.activityInfo.name));
                intent.setAction(Intent.ACTION_SEND);
                intent.setType("text/plain");
                intent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_TEXT, "Text");
                intent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_SUBJECT, "Subject");
                intent.setPackage(packageName);
                targetShareIntents.add(intent);
            }
        }
        if(!targetShareIntents.isEmpty()){
            Intent chooserIntent=Intent.createChooser(targetShareIntents.remove(0), "Choose app to share");
            chooserIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_INITIAL_INTENTS, targetShareIntents.toArray(new Parcelable[]{}));
            startActivity(chooserIntent);
        }else{
            showDialaog(this);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Could you provide some description to solution?