# Customize URL for sharing intent

Tags: android, facebook, android-intent, twitter

It's pretty clear to me how to share a link with the Android sharing Intent...

This is what I usually do:

```
final String extraText = "String 1";
final String searchUrl = "http://www.example.com?utm_source=SOURCE&utm_medium=social&utm_campaign=socialbuttons&utm_content=app_android";
final Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_SEND).setType("text/plain").putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_SUBJECT, "TITLE").putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_TEXT, extraText + "\n" + searchUrl);
```

**BUT**
I would like to customize the tracking in the url for different kind of shares...

Twitter:

`http://www.example.com?utm_source=TWITTER&utm_medium=social&utm_campaign=socialbuttons&utm_content=app_android`

Facebook:

`http://www.example.com?utm_source=FACEBOOK&utm_medium=social&utm_campaign=socialbuttons&utm_content=app_android`

Etc...

Is it possible? How can I do it?

Comment: You need to customize your share dialogue. Please check this [solution](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9730243/how-to-filter-specific-apps-for-action-send-intent-and-set-a-different-text-for)