# Android -- intent chooser for whatsapp and sms only

Tags: android, sms, whatsapp, android-intent-chooser

I want to create an `IntentChooser` who offer to share text only via SMS or WhatsApp.

Here is my code to share via WhatsApp:

```
Intent localIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_SEND);
localIntent.setType("text/plain");
localIntent.setPackage("com.whatsapp");
if (localIntent != null) {
    localIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_TEXT, "Hi there! I'm using this app");
    startActivity(Intent.createChooser(localIntent, "Hi there! I'm using this app"); 
}
```

I need to add to this also sharing with SMS. How can I do it?

Comment: You better make your own chooser with an alert dialog. Not much work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use this for **Whatsapp**.

```
            try {
                startActivity(new Intent(Intent.ACTION_SEND).setType("text/plain").setPackage("com.whatsapp").putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_TEXT, Message));
            } catch (android.content.ActivityNotFoundException ex) {
                Toast.makeText(this, "Whatsapp have not been installed.", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
```

and this for **SMS** .

```
         String number = "12346556";  // The number on which you want to send SMS  
         startActivity(new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, Uri.fromParts("sms", number, null)));
```

**OR**

**Possibly Duplicate** of [Multiple IntentChooser](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9730243/how-to-filter-specific-apps-for-action-send-intent-and-set-a-different-text-for/18068122#18068122)

Comment: Perhaps I did not explain myself well. I want the same `Intent` offer both of these options.

Comment: Just declare intent globally and use for both instead of `new Intent()`. Have got it ??

Comment: No, I want that the `IntentChooser` offer to user only SMS AND WhatsApp. In the same time.

Comment: go through this it help you http://stackoverflow.com/a/18068122/5305430