# How to checkin in Twitter from Android application?

Tags: android, twitter, share

I am developing an android app and I want to share some text content via Twitter. User will just click one button and i will push a tweet like instagram and foursquare. I have done some search but all the examples requires user to click tweet button. I want to sende automatically in the background. I know the text already, user will just click a button. Is there any example for this.

Thank you already.

Comment: use this link http://stackoverflow.com/a/38967146/5305430 and instead of watsapp package name use this `com.twitter.android`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could maybe use [Twitter4J](http://twitter4j.org/en/index.html):

Setup the authentification:

```
ConfigurationBuilder cb = new ConfigurationBuilder();
cb.setDebugEnabled(true)
  .setOAuthConsumerKey("*********************")
  .setOAuthConsumerSecret("******************************************")
  .setOAuthAccessToken("**************************************************")
  .setOAuthAccessTokenSecret("******************************************");
TwitterFactory tf = new TwitterFactory(cb.build());
Twitter twitter = tf.getInstance();
```

Post a tweet:

```
Status status = tf.updateStatus("Hello World!");
```

Answer (score 0):

It is possible to use 
Twitter Rest API

https://docs.fabric.io/android/twitter/access-rest-api.html

E.g.,

https://docs.fabric.io/android/twitter/log-in-with-twitter.html#login-with-twitter

Sample code to retrieve token, secret:

```
TwitterSession session = Twitter.getSessionManager().getActiveSession();
TwitterAuthToken authToken = session.getAuthToken();
String token = authToken.token;
String secret = authToken.secret;
```

Sample code to send a message:

```
TweetComposer.Builder builder = new TweetComposer.Builder(this)
     .text("just setting up my Fabric.")
     .image(myImageUri);
builder.show();
```