# How to filter the apps that show up when sharing intent Android?

Tags: android, android-intent

I know this has been asked before and I reference one of the answers but I can't get my code to work the way it should. I have a simple note-taking app, which allows the user to share notes through external applications. The code is supposed to filter the apps so the user can only share to facebook, twitter, mms, gmail, and email (so I thought). I took it from the top answer here [How to filter specific apps for ACTION_SEND intent (and set a different text for each app)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9730243/how-to-filter-specific-apps-for-action-send-intent-and-set-a-different-text-for). When I click on the button that launches the method to share intents, I do get mms, gmail, facebook twitter, and email, but I also get google drive, android beam, evernote, twitter direct message, facebook messenger and snapchat.

The only apps that the information gets sent correctly to are mms, email and gmail. Facebook doesn't work, there's some comments below on why, and twitter I'm not sure of because I don't have an account to test it out. I don't have the code to check if the packageName contains "drive" or "googledrive", but I can still share to drive and the data from my note gets passed along. I want to be able to send the note text and the note title however (2 editText fields in my app), but I don't know how to since I don't know what the package name is.

For the apps that don't work or I want to remove from the list of choices, how can I get rid of them? Here is the code:

```
public void sendNote(View view) {
    Resources resources = getResources();

    Intent emailIntent = new Intent();
    emailIntent.setAction(Intent.ACTION_SEND);
    // Native email client doesn't currently support HTML, but it doesn't hurt to try in case they fix it
    emailIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_TEXT, titleEditor.getText().toString());
    emailIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_SUBJECT, noteEditor.getText().toString());
    emailIntent.setType("message/rfc822");

    PackageManager pm = getPackageManager();
    Intent sendIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_SEND);
    sendIntent.setType("text/plain");

    Intent openInChooser = Intent.createChooser(emailIntent, titleEditor.getText().toString() + ": " + noteEditor.getText().toString());

    List<ResolveInfo> resInfo = pm.queryIntentActivities(sendIntent, 0);
    List<LabeledIntent> intentList = new ArrayList<LabeledIntent>();
    for (int i = 0; i < resInfo.size(); i++) {
        // Extract the label, append it, and repackage it in a LabeledIntent
        ResolveInfo ri = resInfo.get(i);
        String packageName = ri.activityInfo.packageName;
        if(packageName.contains("android.email")) {
            emailIntent.setPackage(packageName);
        } else if(packageName.contains("twitter") || packageName.contains("facebook") || packageName.contains("mms") || packageName.contains("android.gm")) {
            Intent intent = new Intent();
            intent.setComponent(new ComponentName(packageName, ri.activityInfo.name));
            intent.setAction(Intent.ACTION_SEND);
            intent.setType("text/plain");
            if(packageName.contains("twitter")) {
                intent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_TEXT, titleEditor.getText().toString() + ": " + noteEditor.getText().toString());
            } else if(packageName.contains("facebook")) {
                // Warning: Facebook IGNORES our text. They say "These fields are intended for users to express themselves. Pre-filling these fields erodes the authenticity of the user voice."
                // One workaround is to use the Facebook SDK to post, but that doesn't allow the user to choose how they want to share. We can also make a custom landing page, and the link
                // will show the <meta content ="..."> text from that page with our link in Facebook.
                intent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_TEXT, titleEditor.getText().toString() + ": " + noteEditor.getText().toString());
            } else if(packageName.contains("mms")) {
                intent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_TEXT, titleEditor.getText().toString() + ": " + noteEditor.getText().toString());
            } else if(packageName.contains("android.gm")) { // If Gmail shows up twice, try removing this else-if clause and the reference to "android.gm" above
                intent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_TEXT, noteEditor.getText().toString());
                intent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_SUBJECT, titleEditor.getText().toString());
                intent.setType("message/rfc822");
            }
            //else if (packageName.contains("drive")) {
                //intent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_TEXT, titleEditor.getText().toString() + ": " + noteEditor.getText().toString());
            //}
            else {

            }

            intentList.add(new LabeledIntent(intent, packageName, ri.loadLabel(pm), ri.icon));
        }
    }

    // convert intentList to array
    LabeledIntent[] extraIntents = intentList.toArray( new LabeledIntent[ intentList.size() ]);

    openInChooser.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_INITIAL_INTENTS, extraIntents);
    startActivity(openInChooser);
}
```

I have an else if near the bottom that is commented out. That was my attempt in finding the google drive packageName and sending the intent so the user can still use that application, it didn't work. Like I said earlier, drive gets information sent to it, but it's just the note text, not the title and text like I want it to be.

So I have 2 questions.

1. How can I filter out all of the apps that I don't want the user to be able to send information to so they don't even show up as an option, lets take twitter for example.
2. If the above is not possible, how can I find the package names for these different apps? For Google Drive, I tried using the commented out else if statement to send an intent to the app there but it never executed. I've searched everywhere to get intents for google drive but I can't get the package name to get my code working.

Thanks in advance

Comment: "that I don't want the user to be able to send information to" -- please allow the user to [share where the user wants](https://commonsware.com/blog/2011/06/28/share-where-the-user-wants.html).

Comment: @CommonsWare Thats true I never thought of it like that. I was more going for a proof of concept than anything but I won't worry about that part of the problem now, thanks.