# Custom Image Sharing Dialog to other apps

Tags: android, android-intent

I have an app which shares and receive images from other apps. I have two problems here

- On sharing Image from some other place let say from gallery my app is showing but with its whole package name i.e. com.test.myapp instead of only with the app name

here is the manifest of it

```
    <activity
        android:name=".newdesign.SplashActivity"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:screenOrientation="portrait"
        android:theme="@android:style/Theme.Translucent.NoTitleBar.Fullscreen">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.SEND" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />

            <data android:mimeType="image/*" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
```

- Secondly, Ion sharing the image from my app I don't want to display my own app on the share dialog, but when I remove my app I get some unwanted system apps along with some app with default android icons.

here is the sharing code

```
    List<Intent> targetedShareIntents = new ArrayList<Intent>();
        Intent share = new Intent(android.content.Intent.ACTION_SEND);
        share.setType("image/*");
        List<ResolveInfo> resInfo = ExportOrSaveActivity.this.getPackageManager().queryIntentActivities(createShareIntent(), 0);
        if (!resInfo.isEmpty()) {
            for (ResolveInfo info : resInfo) {
                Intent targetedShare = createShareIntent();
                if (!info.activityInfo.packageName.equalsIgnoreCase("com.test.myapp1") && !info.activityInfo.packageName.equalsIgnoreCase("com.test.myapp2")) {
                    targetedShare.setPackage(info.activityInfo.packageName);
                    targetedShareIntents.add(targetedShare);
                }
            }
            Intent chooserIntent = Intent.createChooser(targetedShareIntents.remove(0),
                    "Select app to share");
            chooserIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_INITIAL_INTENTS,
                    targetedShareIntents.toArray(new Parcelable[] {}));
            startActivity(chooserIntent);
```

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Still Not Sure about the first issue, but found a solution to the second one .

Here is the code to create you own share dialog with whichever apps you want

```
final  List<Item> items=new ArrayList<>();

        Intent audioIntent = new Intent(android.content.Intent.ACTION_SEND);
        audioIntent.setDataAndType(Uri.parse("file://" + MainActivity.sSavedImagePath), "image/*");
        List<ResolveInfo> audio = ExportOrSaveActivity.this.getPackageManager().queryIntentActivities(audioIntent, 0);
        for (ResolveInfo info : audio){
            String label = info.loadLabel(ExportOrSaveActivity.this.getPackageManager()).toString();
            Drawable icon = info.loadIcon(ExportOrSaveActivity.this.getPackageManager());
            String packageName = info.activityInfo.packageName;
            String name = info.activityInfo.name;
            Item ita=new Item(label , packageName ,icon );
            if (!info.activityInfo.packageName.equalsIgnoreCase("com.package.toskip") && !info.activityInfo.packageName.equalsIgnoreCase("com.package.toskiptoo")) {
                items.add(ita);
            }

        }


        ListAdapter adapter = new ArrayAdapter<Item>(
                this,
                android.R.layout.select_dialog_item,
                android.R.id.text1,
                items){
            public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
                //Use super class to create the View
                View v = super.getView(position, convertView, parent);
                TextView tv = (TextView)v.findViewById(android.R.id.text1);

                //Put the image on the TextView
                tv.setCompoundDrawablesWithIntrinsicBounds(items.get(position).icon, null, null, null);

                //Add margin between image and text (support various screen densities)
                int dp5 = (int) (5 * getResources().getDisplayMetrics().density + 0.5f);
                tv.setCompoundDrawablePadding(dp5);
                tv.setTextColor(R.color.black);

                return v;
            }
        };


        new AlertDialog.Builder(ExportOrSaveActivity.this,android.R.style.Theme_Holo_Light)
                .setTitle("Share Image")
                .setAdapter(adapter, new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                    public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int item) {
                        Intent share = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_SEND);
                        share.setPackage(items.get(item).packagename);
                        share.setType("image/*");
                        share.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_STREAM, Uri.parse("file://" + MainActivity.sSavedImagePath));
                        startActivity(share);

                    }
                }).show();
```

Hope it help other who are looking for some thing similar.

Answer (score 0):

```
public static Intent shareImage(Context context, String pathToImage) {
    Intent shareIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_SEND);
    if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT < Build.VERSION_CODES.LOLLIPOP)
        shareIntent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_WHEN_TASK_RESET);
    else
        shareIntent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_DOCUMENT);
    shareIntent.setType("image/*");
    // For a file in shared storage.  For data in private storage, use a ContentProvider.
    Uri uri = Uri.fromFile(context.getFileStreamPath(pathToImage));
    shareIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_STREAM, uri);
    return shareIntent;
}

refer this http://android-developers.blogspot.com/2012/02/share-with-intents.html
```

Comment: "on sharing the image from my app I don't want to display my own app on the share dialog," how does this help?

Comment: are you using <data android:mimeType="image/*" />
            <data android:mimeType="text/*" /> on your android AndroidManifest

Comment: remove  <data android:mimeType="image/*" />

Comment: no need to use   <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.SEND" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
            <data android:mimeType="image/*" />
        </intent-filter>

Comment: Why? by doing so my app won't be able to receive the image from other apps.

Comment: look this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9730243/how-to-filter-specific-apps-for-action-send-intent-and-set-a-different-text-for/18068122#18068122

Comment: Not via createChooser(). You can create your own chooser-like dialog via PackageManager and queryIntentActivities() and filter yourself out that way, though.