# How to know what social media someone selected

Tags: android, android-intent

Is it possible to tell what social media someone has selected?

What I want to do is share certain text based on what they have chosen. ie I dont want to include #'s in sms, whatsapps etc but i want them on Twitter facebook etc?

Thanks

Comment: you can check file extension.

Comment: could you elaborate?

Comment: You want to know what sharing application the user has chosen. Is it ?

Comment: yea, when using the intent "sendIntent.setAction(Intent.ACTION_SEND);" I want to know which option the user selected so I can send a specfic style of text

Comment: @SilentKiller thats so far off the idea. totally unrelated to this question

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/18068122/1160282 this one ?