# How can I share referral code on facebook,whatapp,instagram and other platforms in android

Tags: android, branch.io

I am having a screen through which user can share referral code on Facebook, WhatsApp, Twitter and Instagram. (I already have an API to generate referral codes). Now I was going through branch.io documentation. But all I could find was deep linking. I am not able to understand how to use branch.io to share the referral codes across all these platforms or should I use something else to program this functionality.

My app screenshot[image: referral code screen]

Answer (score 1):

Alex from Branch.io here.

We actually used to offer a referral *code* feature exactly as you've described, but deprecated it a while back in favor of a referral *link* system. The reason why is actually quite interesting: our partner apps found codes unnecessary and a lot of extra work. The way Branch handles referrals is fundamentally different and far more user-friendly, so you actually don't need to make the user enter a code at all.

## Traditional app referral process

1. `Inviting User` gets a code
2. `Inviting User` gives a code to a friend (`Invited User`) and says 'go download this app and enter my code!'
3. `Invited User` hopefully downloads the app, hopefully finds out how to enter a code, hopefully enters the code correctly
4. `Inviting User` gets a reward

As you can see, plenty of places where that process can go wrong.

## Branch referral process

1. `Inviting User` gets a link
2. `Inviting User` sends the link to a friend (`Invited User`)
3. `Invited User` clicks the link, is sent directly to the Play Store, downloads the app, and *automatically triggers the referral redemption logic without any manual work*
4. `Inviting User` gets a reward

This works because Branch tracks the user who originally created the link, and can report back on that when the new user successfully downloads/purchases/whatever else the first time after opening the link. It is a much simpler and more seamless process, and the Branch referral infrastructure is so reliable that it 'just works'.

Here is the documentation page for setting this up: https://dev.branch.io/features/referral-programs/

## Using the Share Sheet

Branch offers a [pre-built share sheet](https://dev.branch.io/getting-started/branch-universal-object/guide/android/#showsharesheet) on Android that you can use to post these links via any installed app. It may not be especially useful to you because you've already built your own custom icons, but it would avoid an error if one of those apps is not available.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

This will allow you to share on every application possible

```
Intent sharingIntent = new Intent(android.content.Intent.ACTION_SEND);
            sharingIntent.setType("text/plain");
            sharingIntent.putExtra(android.content.Intent.EXTRA_SUBJECT, "Subject Here");
            sharingIntent.putExtra(android.content.Intent.EXTRA_TEXT, "share content");
            startActivity(Intent.createChooser(sharingIntent, "share using"));
```

Comment: how can this be used to share referral code on facebook,instagram,whatsapp and twitter?

Comment: implement this code on the onclickListener of your share option and this will give you a dynamic share option from apps like facebook, gmail, skype , whatsapp etc which are installed on your mobile

Answer (score 0):

Why not send referal code / link using sharing intent

```
Intent sendIntent = new Intent();
sendIntent.setAction(Intent.ACTION_SEND);
sendIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_TEXT, "This is my text to send.");
sendIntent.setType("text/plain");
startActivity(sendIntent);
```

see the [Documentation](https://developer.android.com/training/sharing/send.html) for more info

and you can filter the app using the answer over [Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9730243/how-to-filter-specific-apps-for-action-send-intent-and-set-a-different-text-for)

Answer (score 0):

Best way to share such information is via http url's as most of the sharing platforms don't allow to post pre-filled text.

Most of the sharing platforms read the meta content inside the html page of the url and make a post accordingly.

Go through this link for meta tags to be used for `Facebook` :-
https://developers.facebook.com/docs/sharing/webmasters

And, for sharing links use this:-

```
Intent share = new Intent(android.content.Intent.ACTION_SEND);
        share.setType("text/plain");
        share.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_WHEN_TASK_RESET);

        share.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_SUBJECT, "Title Of The Post");
        share.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_TEXT, "<source url>");

        startActivity(Intent.createChooser(share, "Share text to..."));
```

Comment: how can this be used to share referral code on facebook,instagram,whatsapp and twitter?

Comment: Create a html and put it on your server and share it's link via android or iphone devices. For more details checkout:-https://developers.facebook.com/docs/sharing/webmasters

Comment: This code is common for all platforms no need to change if you are sharing url of  the page.

Comment: Can i programatically only open facebook when facebook icon is clicked?

Comment: you can use @Jehad answer for sharing on specific platform.