# Adjustable "Share via" in Android

Tags: android, share, html-email, whatsapp

I'm trying to implement an adjustable share in android.
An Example of use:

- The user choose to share via Email -  i will generate an Html to be the body of the mail.
- The user choose to share via WhatsApp or Facebook - i will generate a link.

I thought i will find a callback for the **Intent.createChooser**, how ever i found a callback only for the post action.

Is there a way to achieve what i m looking for, or is there any intelligent way to be able allowing multiple share methods?

Comment: One way is doing it is creating your custom Chooser Intent, separate for Email and separate for Whatsapp - Facebook.

Comment: @Arshad have you done it?

Comment: I haven't tried it. But you can have look here. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9730243/how-to-filter-specific-apps-for-action-send-intent-and-set-a-different-text-for Or You can create a  custom app chooser popup and then invoke Intent for selected app