# How to get first two chooser intents and display only them for user in android

Tags: android, android-intent, android-intent-chooser

I'm trying to display only gallery and File manager in the chooser intent

So, i tried something like below

```
Intent intent = new Intent();
                intent.setType("image/*");
                intent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_ALLOW_MULTIPLE, true);
                intent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_LOCAL_ONLY,true);
                intent.setAction(Intent.ACTION_PICK);
                startActivityForResult(Intent.createChooser(intent, "Select Picture"), RESULT_LOAD_IMAGE);
```

But along with gallery and File Explorer it is showing other apps too. It is also showing google drive

So, i decided to choose only first two intents and remove others.

How to achieve this ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For your case the easiest way to achieve what you need is

to add below line

```
intent.setData(android.provider.MediaStore.Images.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI);
```

By adding above line you can get rid of installed apps by user. 
but be aware of one thing

- when you use `intent.setAction(Intent.ACTION_PICK);` you will see Gallery, File Manager, and Any Inbuilt photo app provider by manufacturer of phone.
- when you use `intent.setAction(Intent.ACTION_GET_CONTENT);` along with above you will also see Google drive.

> Don't go for first two chooser intents it is not recommended and I don't know the reason, Also I don't know how to do that.

Hope, This gives a proper explanation with answer.

Comment: This is just a straight forward answer what i'm expecting. Thank you

Comment: I don't suggest first two intents filter. if you still want refer here https://stackoverflow.com/a/22368585/12773602

Comment: I don't need that technique anymore. The above answer is enough for my project.

Answer (score 2):

use this type of code :

```
Intent i= new Intent(Intent.ACTION_GET_CONTENT);
    i.setType("image/*");

    Intent pickIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_PICK, android.provider.MediaStore.Images.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI);
    pickIntent.setType("image/*");

    Intent chooserIntent = Intent.createChooser(i, "Select Image");
    chooserIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_INITIAL_INTENTS, new Intent[] {pickIntent});

    startActivityForResult(chooserIntent, PICK_IMAGE);
```