# iOS / Android Share - Show specific share options / custom share spec

Tags: android, ios, popup, share

Is it possible to bypass the first stage of the default share pop up on Android and iOS so that an app can have a specific button for sharing with WhatsApp contacts and an entirely different button for say Messenger contacts.

IF that is not possible or is only possible with app authorisations from Facebook, is it possible to limit the share options available in the share popover. Our app content should only be available to be shared with individuals not posted on social media - hence the problem.

Comment: For Android I would have a look at this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/18068122/

Comment: For iOS you might need to create a sharing options manually. Here is an example for the WhatsApp integration https://faq.whatsapp.com/iphone/how-to-link-to-whatsapp-from-a-different-app

Comment: @KaterynaGridina I read that too and it might work. I was just hoping that someone else might have encountered this and was being lazy enough to ask accordingly. If either of the methods in the comments above accurately answer the original question I'll post exactly how it was done. Thanks for your comments.